# Linked list assignment

Tags: c

Hi I have an assignment that asks me to create a linked list
and populate it with integers 0 to 10. I have done that already.
The problem I'm having is with the last part which is to have
a seperate user defined function that gets passed a pointer that
points to the head of the list. When I do that and try to printf
the integer from the list I get an error saying that it is not
something in a structure or a union. Please help, I'm pretty stumped
on what to do next.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    struct list
    {                //creating structure
       int num;
       struct list *next;  //used to point to next node on list
    };

    struct list *head;             //used to navigate the linked list
    struct list *current;
    struct list *new;
    head=malloc(sizeof(struct list));  //gives memory space to start off linked list
    head->num=0;
    head->next=NULL;
    current=head;                      //current equals head now so that one can easily navigate the list with the loop

    int c=0;                      //loop counter int
    while(c<11)      //populates the linked list with integers
    {
       new=malloc(sizeof(struct list));
       current->next=new;
       if(current->next == NULL)    //checks to see if memory created
       printf("This has failed");
       current=new;
       current->num=c+1;
       c++;
    }
    struct list **headptr=&head;   //PROBLEM: I'm assuming here is where I'm having the issue.
    print(headptr);
}

void printList(struct list** head) {
    int x;  //loop counter
    struct list *current;
    while (x<11) {
        if(x==0)
           printf("%d",head.num);
        current
        printf("%d",current->num);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the compiler output?

Comment: also main should be declared as `int main(void)` instead of `int main()`. The latter is an obsolescent feature of the language.

Comment: Have you check there's no any typo in your post. It seems that this will cause compiling error.

Comment: Is this really your code? `printList` just has too many errors. 1. `while (x<11)`: `x` is never assigned anywhere before, within or after the loop.  2. `head.num`: Should be `(*head)->num`. 3. `current`: That makes no sense by itself. 4. `current->num`: `current` had never been assigned. Not sure it is worth commenting anymore short of re-writing the entire function.

Comment: Right, I stopped writing printlist because it gave an error at head.num. Thanks for the advice. Even if I correct it with your suggestions I still get an error, dereferenceing pointer to an incomplete type.Error occurs at *head-> num line.

Comment: I said `(*head)->num` not `*head->num`. It makes a difference. And please, when you post code on SO make sure that it is valid code as far as you can. Otherwise people will waste time commenting on those parts of the code that you don't really need help with (yet).

Comment: printf("%d",((*head)->num); .... That's what I put and it gives me that error. I'll keep that in mind for next time. First time posting on here.

Comment: Oh, you have the `struct list` definition inside `main` which makes it available only to that function. Place it outside (above `main`) so that it is scoped/available to the whole file.

Comment: Thank you, I modified my code a bit and it worked out. Just had to dereference like you said, put struct outside main and change the while loop so that it goes through the linked list better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

I make some changes in your code..

1.Here your are using two function hence we need to declare structure globally. So that both the function can use prototype of structure

2.C language has top-down type of approach hence we need to give prototype of `printList` function at the top of program or define function in top itself

3.In `while(c<11)` block we have to add the statement `current->next=NULL` to identify end position of list which is used in `printList` function

4.When we use `malloc` function type conversion is must.

5.It is not needed to send `headptr` by address. It increase the complexity of program. So just I changed that portion to somewhat easier method

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list
{                //creating structure
    int num;
    struct list *next;  //used to point to next node on list
};

void printList(struct list* head)
{
    while(head->next!=NULL)
    {
      printf("%d ",head->num);
      head=head->next;
    }

}
int main()
{
    struct list *head;             //used to navigate the linked list
    struct list *current;
    struct list *newp;
    head=(struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));  //gives memory space to start off linked list
    head->num=0;
    head->next=NULL;
    current=head;                      //current equals head now so that one can easily navigate the list with the loop

    int c=0;                      //loop counter int
    while(c<11)      //populates the linked list with integers
    {
       newp=(struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
       current->next=newp;
       current=newp;
       current->num=c+1;
       current->next=NULL;
       c++;
    }
    struct list *headptr=head;   //PROBLEM: I'm assuming here is where I'm having the issue.
    printList(headptr);
}
```

Comment: What did you change and why were the changes you made necessary? That type of explanation, at minimum is generally expected in a answer. You may also want to explain why `headptr` is unnecessary, and that a `freeList` type function to free the memory that was allocated should also be used. Try and pass on that information necessary to a full understanding of proper coding regarding the question. It helps the OP and everyone that visits this answer thereafter.